# No /etc/mdadm.conf in centos 6

Tags: centos, raid, software-raid, mdadm

I have installed centos 6 and setup a new RAID array with two disks. every thing is ok and I have partitioned the array but I don't see any `/etc/mdadm.conf` or `/etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf` files. I have rebooted my machine too but no luck!

Can you tell me what is my mistake? Is there a change in the location of the mdadm configuration files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That file isn't typically included in the `mdadm` package.

```
$ rpm -ql mdadm | grep "mdadm.conf"
/usr/share/doc/mdadm-2.6.9/mdadm.conf-example
/usr/share/man/man5/mdadm.conf.5.gz
```

You can either use the sample one included or generate it your self. My file shows this in the header:

```
# mdadm.conf written out by anaconda
```

So it was likely built by some choices I must've made during installation, would be my guess. I've typically run this command to generate this file by hand as root:

```
$ mdadm --verbose --detail --scan > /etc/mdadm.conf
```

Without the redirect to the `/etc/mdadm.conf` file this command will produce something similar to this:

```
$ mdadm --verbose --detail --scan 
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid1 num-devices=2 metadata=0.90 UUID=48b4cedc:52404142:34d244f7:3b879f08
   devices=/dev/sda1,/dev/sdb1
```

I then add the following line to the end of the file if I want to be notified via email if there's any issues:

```
MAILADDR user1@dom1.com, user2@dom2.com
```

Comment: does any problem occur if this file does not exist?

Comment: The RAID should still function correctly: "When your RAID is correctly configured, the md driver is able to get everything it needs off the superblocks in the RAID components themselves. The mdadm.conf file is really just there to help guide it along when there might be some ambiguity." [mdadm.conf empty... where is my config?](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1447155)

Comment: Check this one:

http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7001034


On bottom example with cron check